# How to draw the bitmap by using custom view

Tags: android, android-view

I want to draw the circle with the dot image by using custom view ,and how to animate the dotted circle like glow in lock screen.

please give me proper suggestion

[image]

Comment: I think you should go with Canvas....And if there is different requirement then post image what you need??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyView extends View{
    ... constructors ...
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap,...); //check the link
    }
}
```

[this is the link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)